# Windows 10 Professional 64-bit limited to 32 GB of RAM?

Tags: windows-10, memory, memory-limit

I have a system running Windows 10 Professional and in the system I have installed 4 identical sticks of 16GB RAM, making a total of 64GB.

Yet my system only reads a total of 32GB when checking DXDiag, checking system info marks it as 28GB.

I have done plenty of research around the net and everything I search for only returns results related to peoples limitations of 4GB on 32-bit systems, but this is a 64-bit system and I know the theoretical limit for RAM on it is way beyond 32GB or even 64GB.

I know lower editions of Windows may limit your RAM usage but again, this system is running Windows 10 Proffesional 64-bit. Is there some bottleneck or limitation I am not aware of?

Motherboard  Model Biostar  TZ77A

Comment: It would not be an OS limit. I would look at your motherboard specs.

Comment: System Information report written at: 03/09/16 12:18:15
System Name: STREETS
[System Summary]

Item Value 
OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Pro 
Version 10.0.10586 Build 10586 
Other OS Description  Not Available 
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation 
System Name STREETS 
System Manufacturer BIOSTAR Group 
System Model TZ77A 
System Type x64-based PC 
System SKU None 
Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3240 CPU @ 3.40GHz, 3400 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s) 
BIOS Version/Date American Megatrends Inc. 4.6.5, 4/19/2012 
SMBIOS Version 2.7 
Embedded Controller Version 255.255 
BIOS Mode Legacy

Comment: Please edit your post and put this information there. Then you can edit it so that it will actually be easy to read.

Answer (score 2):

From [THIS](http://www.techadvice.com/info/item.asp?cid=959&pid=37&iid=342220) page:

> Maximum Memory Supported  32GB - 64bit
>
> Number of Slots   4 Max.
>
> Memory Supported Per Slot 8GB

Comment: Thank you very much. I was losing my mind pondering the limitations, I had a guess that it may be the motherboard but didn't know how to confirm.

Comment: @DJSeras Best way to confirm is usually on the specs for the motherboard.  Depending where you buy it, it could be on the box and/or on the webpage you are purchasing it from.  I make it a habit to check Max Ram Speed and Size (per slot and total) each time i'm looking at motherboards, so I can make a plan on what RAM I will need and can use (if you have old sticks).

Comment: Worth pointing out the 32 GB limit is due the motherboard and has nothing to do with a limitation surrounding Windows 10.